# What's wrong with atoi?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write program that read file and summarize all numbers which are in interval from 0 through 9 so it can recognize number 6 as 6 and number 12 as 1 and 2 or something like that. Here is the code which normally summarize numbers from 0 through 9 but deffedctively summarize numbers like 12. For example I give atoi function pointer that points to 1 and atoi returns number 12 instead of 1 and then it returns 2 so sum of this numbers will be 14 instead of 3.Have no idea why it happens!Thank you all for fruitful solutions.

```
void sumNumbers(FILE *INCOME_stream)
{

  char defaultNumbers[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
  char* defNum_ptr=defaultNumbers;
  char stream_string[maxLength];
  char* stream_string_ptr=stream_string;
  while(fgets(stream_string_ptr,maxLength,INCOME_stream)!=NULL)
  {  int numb=0;

   int stringLength=strlen(stream_string_ptr);
   for(int z=0;z<stringLength;z++)
   {
     for(int h=0;h<sizeof(defaultNumbers);h++)
     {
       if(*(stream_string_ptr+z)==*(defNum_ptr+h))
       {
         numb+=atoi(stream_string_ptr+z);

     }
     }
   }
 printf("sum=%d ",numb);
 }
```

Comment: Beside the code missing a closing bracket, it would be useful if you could post the content of the input file and the expected output

Comment: `atoi` is working correctly.  it takes a null terminated string and attempts to convert it to an integer.  (although it doesn't tell you when it fails).  when you call `atoi("12")` it will return 12.  when you call `atoi("2")` it will return 2.  if you want the number `1` from the string `"12"` then you should not use atoi.  or just copy the first character `1` into a temporary null terminated buffer.

Comment: ... in particular, perhaps you want `stream_string_ptr[z] - '0'`.

Comment: fu** , i totally forget about that feature. Thx a lot for reminding me.@John Bollinger

Comment: atoi('X') returns zero.   In effect there is no way to detect if the function call was successful or not.

Comment: Because "12" converted to a number is 12?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that array are already pointer, this is what i would suggest: 
Use strtol to scan the string as the endptr feature works perfectly for this purpose

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define maxLength 20

void sumNumbers(FILE *INCOME_stream)
{
    char stream_string[maxLength];
    while(fgets(stream_string, maxLength, INCOME_stream) != NULL)
    {
        int numb = 0;
        int app;
        int stringLength = strlen(stream_string);

        char *endptr = stream_string;
        while( endptr - stream_string < stringLength - 1)
        {
            app = strtol( endptr, &endptr, 10);
            if( app >=0 && app < 10)
                numb += app;
        }

        printf("sum=%d ", numb);
    }
}

int main()
{
    sumNumbers( stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nit-pick: An array is not a pointer, but it can decay into one.